# open an especific app from notification Action Button on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I am working in a piece of functionality for an IOS app (with objective C) with local notifications using UserNotification framework.
By now, I was able to schedule a notification and It gets display properly. When I reach the issue with Actionable Notification Types (With Categories and Actions) I manage to display a notification with the Action. I actually could implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` correctly and verified if `didReceiveNotificationResponse` method was being call, and it was. But my problem is that I was trying to open maps app from there using URL scheme like this

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler{

NSString * mapsURL = @"http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=35.6813023,139.7640529&daddr=33.4657901,132.6201192";

//if ( [response.actionIdentifier isEqualToString:@"GoToMaps" ]) {

    //Display the map with URL
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mapsURL] options:@{}  completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"BOOL value: %d",success);
    }];
//}

completionHandler();
}
```

NOTE: I am testing this app in a simulator.

But this does not work because when the app is in background, this gives me 0 on `success` arg. But when I try this in a button that is in my app (application in foreground), this actually works.
So my question is:

Is there a way I can open a different app (from where the notification was schedule) from Action buttons in the notification, not just maps, I mean, whatever app even if the app is closed or in background ?

I said closed app but Apples documentation says that when a User selects and action, the system launches the app in the background and notifies the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object, which notifies its delegate. So it´s not going to be really closed (not running).

Comment: For as long I been researching. I found that is not posible to open an app with URL schema from another if this is not in foreground

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. At the moment you define the Notification action, you set the actionIdenfier, title and the options. The options arg needs to have `UNNotificationActionOptionForeground` option, which according to Apple documentation, will cause the app open in foreground, then in didReceiveNotificationResponse method if you have openURL you will be redirect to the app or safari according to the url schema.